# RxJS handling success with async pipe

Tags: angular, timer, rxjs, observable, emit

So basically I want to do following:

I have a backend call and template in Angular 6

After this backend call I want to switchMap the result to dataUpdated$ observable which will display something in template like:

`<h1 *ngIf="dataUpdated$ | async">Very Good!</h1>`

and then I want to set timer on the same stream and after lets say 2 seconds I want to update that observable again so it disappears in template.

I don't want to use subscribe method, I have subscription in code already.

I want to update to code to be one stream without breaking or needing to unsubscribe manually

Comment: You can write a pipe to insert between `dataUpdated$` and the `async` pipe. Or you can use a library like this: https://github.com/tibing/async-pipeline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `async` pipe should keep only one subscription so you can use `switchMap` to just reemit the original value and after 2s emit `false` that should hide the message.

```
dataUpdated$ = source.pipe(
  switchMap(v => merge(
    of(v),
    of(false).pipe(delay(2000)),
  )),
);
```

Comment: I like this answer but I want to start the timer after the `of(v)` finishes, P.S I managed to do it